# A trigonometric lower bound

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality

I would like to prove that

$$\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} \ge {1 \over 4}$$

for $|x|<1$ and $x\neq0$.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried finding the minimizer of $(1-\cos(x))/x^{2}$ on $[-1,1]$ and just checking that the value of the function at that point is at least $1/4$?

Comment: Try to apply the Taylor series of $\cos x=1-\frac {x^2} 2+\frac {x^4}{24}+\cdot\cdot\cdot$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality is obvious for $x = 0$ and the left-hand side is even in $x$ so we may assume $x \in (0,1)$. Taylor's theorem implies that
$$ \cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{\xi^4}{24}$$
for some $\xi \in (0,x)$, so
$$ \frac{1- \cos x}{x^2} = \frac12 - \frac{\xi^4}{24x^2}.$$
Hence it is enough to show that $\xi^4/x^2 < 6$ for any $\xi \in (0,x)$. But this is obvious because...

Answer (score 1):

Since $\cos$ is an even function, we can assume $0<x<1$.
we need to prove that $$\frac{2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{x^2}\geq\frac{1}{4}$$ or
$$\sin\frac{x}{2}\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cdot\frac{x}{2}.$$
Let $f(x)=\sin{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}x$, where $0<x<0.5$.

Thus, $$f'(x)=\cos{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}>\cos\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}>0,$$
which says $f(x)\geq f(0)=0$ and we are done!

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4!}x^2+\frac{1}{6!}x^4+O(x^6)$$
where the terms after the $\frac12$ are bounded by $$\frac{1}{4!}+\frac{1}{5!}+\cdots=e-\left(1+1+\frac12+\frac16\right)\approx0.05$$

Answer (score 0):

By the concavity of the sine function over $(0,1)$ we have
$$\forall x\in(0,1),\qquad  \sin(1)x\leq \sin(x) \leq x \tag{1} $$
and by termwise integration it follows that
$$ \forall x\in(0,1),\qquad \sin(1)\frac{x^2}{2}\leq 1-\cos(x) \leq \frac{x^2}{2}\tag{2} $$
so
$$ \forall x\in(0,1),\qquad 0.42 \leq \frac{\sin(1)}{2}\leq \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} \leq \frac{1}{2} = 0.5.\tag{3} $$